# How to use space in arguments for Maven 2 exec plugin

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, maven-plugin

Related Question: [Maven Exec Plugin not reading configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046800/maven-exec-plugin-not-reading-configuration)

In my configuration I need an argument which is a file path. I found a rather "dirty" workaround by surrounding the argument with quotes in the POM ("dirty" because the argument will be passed to the main method with these quotes, they have to be removed again in the code).

```
<configuration>
    <executable>java</executable>
    <arguments>
        <argument>"path to file"</argument>
    </arguments>
</configuration>
```

However I have found no solution for passing the path as a command line argument:

```
>mvn exec:java -Dexec.args="path to file"
```

Answer (score 17):

In general, maven requires the whole argument to be quoted if there is space in the argument value.

```
mvn exec:java "-Dexec.args=path to file"
```

Answer (score 3):

On the command line, you may try using single-quotes (but I'm not sure if it works), e.g.:

```
>mvn exec:java -Dexec.args="'path to file' arg2 arg3"
```

Comment: I tried without success on Windows. (On Linux, no spaces are allowed in file / path names :-)

Comment: Fails on mac os too. Why answer if you don't know the answer?

Comment: Works for me on Linux!  ;-)

Comment: Works for me on Mac OS X El Captain 10.11.6, Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T15:39:06-04:00)

Answer (score 3):

Use `-Dexec.args="'space parameter' normalparameter 'one more space parameter'"`

I've tried it on Windows and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in command line try: `$ mvn exec:java -Dexec.args="path\ to\ file arg2 arg3"`

Answer (score 0):

Try `-Dexec.arguments="path to file"` (instead of `-Dexec.args="path to file"`)

[Check here for details.](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html)